# Rewrite rule to work consistently for subdomain and subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a nice rule for rewriting the url to /meetings, but the rule doesn't rewrite the url properly when visited from a subdirectory.

*EDIT: My .htaccess file is in the subdirectory /blog*

When I use this rule:...

```
RewriteRule ^meetings$ /?page_id=2809 [L]
```

When visited from subdomain(*blog.example.com/meetings*): **blog.example.com/meetings**

When visited from subdirectory(*example.com/blog/meetings*): **404 error**

When I use this rule:...

```
RewriteRule ^meetings$ http://blog.example.com/?page_id=2809 [L]
```

When visited from subdomain(*blog.example.com/meetings*): **blog.example.com/meetings**

When visited from subdirectory(*example.com/blog/meetings*): **blog.example.com/?page_id=2809**

*Is there a way to get the rule to work consistently for the subdomain and the subdirectory?*

Comment: What URL's you are requesting? Please update the question.

Comment: just blog.example.com/meetings and example.com/blog/meetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this in one .htaccess file in `/blog` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}      blog\.example\.com               [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   !page_id=                        [NC]
RewriteRule ^meetings         /?page_id=2809                   [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}      ^(www\.)?example\.com            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   !page_id=                        [NC]
RewriteRule ^meetings         /blog/?page_id=2809              [L,NC]
```

For permanent redirection, replace [L,NC] with [R=301,L,NC].

Comment: I get "Not found" when visiting from: `blog.example.com/meetings'

Comment: Added a leading slash. Please try again. If still doesn't work, 2 questions: Does `example.com/meetings` work as expected and is `blog` an addon sub-domain hosted at `example.com/blog`?

Comment: This worked! Could you explain why the RewriteCond's are necessary and what exactly does -MultiViews do? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: MultiViews allows resource negotiation, which is best explained [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html). mod_rewrite does not work correctly with that option enabled and that's why it is important to disable it to use that module. The RewriteCond are used to select the hosts the requests are to and apply the rules accordingly, and to prevent loops (!page_id=).